# why is python script failing to download webpages through a proxy

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

i am new to python and am trying my luck at sockets. So i wrote a simple http client but to my surprise it is failing to access webpages that firefox can access, yet they use the same headers

```
import socket
clientsocket= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(("213.229.83.205",80))#connect to proxy at given address
print "connected to 213.229.83.205"
sdata= """GET http://google.co.ug/ HTTP/1.1
Host: google.co.ug
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: cookie <-- Real cookie deleted

"""
print "sending request"
clientsocket.send(sdata);
rdata=clientsocket.recv(10240)
if not rdata: print "no data found"
else:
    print "receiving data !"
    myfile=open("c:/users/markdenis/desktop/google.html","w")
    myfile.write(str(rdata))
    myfile.close()
    print "data written to file on desktop"
clientsocket.close()
raw_input()#system(pause)
```

When i run it, it shows:

```
connected to 213.229.83.205
sending request
no data found
```

Comment: There is a glype proxy running at the address above

Comment: Are you sure your line breaks between and after the headers are `\r\n`? It is required by some servers (most in my experience.)

Comment: can I know the objective of your code, any special reason for not using urllib2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP protocol requires `\r\n` at the end of each header and an extra on a blank line at the end of the HTTP headers.  You aren't explicit about the line endings in your `sdata` buffer, and therefore your buffer ends up with just `\n` line endings.

Tested on Windows, Linux and OS X, to be sure:

```
>>> x = """a
b
c"""
>>> x
'a\\nb\\nc\\n'
```

Where you need:

```
>>> x = "a\r\nb\r\nc\r\n"
>>> x
'a\\r\\nb\\r\\nc\\r\\n'
```

Add `\r\n`s and give it a shot.  Doing it directly in the buffer will get you an extra set of `\n`, so split it up:

```
sdata = "GET http://google.co.ug/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"
sdata += "Host: google.co.ug\r\n"
sdata += "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0\r\n"
sdata += "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
sdata += "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n"
sdata += "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
sdata += "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
sdata += "\r\n"
```